# Unable to filter Mono of Map

Tags: functional-programming, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, flux

```
    Mono> t = taxCodeByUpc.flatMap( avaTaxCodesMap-> {
                //fetching list inside and logged as well
                List missedUpc = avaTaxCodesMap
                    .keySet()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(avaTaxCodes ->avaTaxCodes.equals(TaxCoreRepository.DEFAULT_AVATAX_CODE))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
                if (!missedUpc.isEmpty()) {

                   // do something
                }
                return Mono.just(avaTaxCodesMap);
            });
```

code is having taxCodeByUpc which is a map , which i am trying to filter , but this expression not working, while debugging i got to know debugger not even going inside from first line itself .  In the output i want Map with entry only which satisfies condition.

Comment: is anything subscribing to the mono `t`? Without a subscription nothing will ever happen.

Comment: The mono tag is not for Java. Don't misuse it.

Comment: @MichaelMcFadyen i am new to Spring-Webflux , but i am not using t further , specially not subscribing .


But motive is to filter map and log if filtered value are not empty !
Can you help on this ?  how i can use subscribe functionality

Comment: the most common approach is to allow spring boot to subscribe to your Mono for you. You would do this by returning the instance of the Mono from either the Controller method or your HandlerFunction depending on which approach you have taken for defining your REST endpoints.